# Bypassing HTML encoding

Tags: xss, html, encoding

I am testing a web application where the server accepts special characters like `@#$*`, but when I insert double / single quotes, the server HTML encodes it.

```
("test&quot;&gt;%3Cscript%3Ealert(&#39;XSS&#39;)%3C%2Fscript%3E")
```

is the output from the server.

How can I bypass this HTML encoding?

Comment: The question is not clear, and needs revision. You can use markup formatting.

Comment: i am getting a reflection point in the Application where it is accepting special characters @#$, but not accepting single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: How can i by pass the server validation to execute cross-site-scripting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exploit XSS, you need to be able to inject HTML into the page. If the `<` and `>` characters are escaped, it is not possible to inject a tag. If the `"` and `'` characters are esacped, it is not possible to inject an attribute. So it seems the page you are testing is safe from XSS.

Comment: ...unless it injects data directly into (some parts of) a script tag or an unquoted attribute.