# how to bypass URL encoding on XSS

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I typed following script on the search input on the website alert() but website converted this script into

*`&lt;script&gt;alert()&lt;/script&gt;`*

in HTML content, is there any possible way to bypass this security

Comment: Lemme know if you find one.Will finally get paid

Comment: That's actually not URL encoding (which would be `%HH`) but HTML encoding (`&...;`). Possible duplicate of [Bypassing HTML encoding](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147870/bypassing-html-encoding). In short: no way.